# Angularjs can't get eggheadio $http example to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to follow the tutorial at the following https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-http

The error I get is TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

I have the following directory structure:

```
expressproject/
    index.js
angularproject/
    app.js
    index.html
```

My index.js file looks like the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(cors());
app.set('port', 3000);

app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
  res.send({hello: 'World'})
})

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

My app.js file looks like:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function($http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:3000/users')
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    })
})
```

My index.html file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Http test</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl in app">

<script src='angular.js'></script>
<script src='app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the express server and point my web browser at

```
(http://localhost:3000/users)
```

I get:

```
{
  "hello": "World"
}
```

which is what I would expect.
I have tried running the angularjs part with the python SimpleHTTPServer and without any server and I still get the same error.

Comment: Which line of code, of which file, does the `TypeError` relate to?

Comment: "I get: ... which is what I would expect."  So what's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ng-controller` syntax is incorrect, instead of:

```
ng-controller="AppCtrl in app"
```

It should be just:

```
ng-controller="AppCtrl"
```

or if you need an alias:

```
ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl"
```

The compiler doesn't recognize the `in` token hence the error occurred.

Comment: Thank you runTarm your right. I changed in to as and now it works. It also works with ng-controller="AppCtrl as app"